# Best idea for Offline sync in app

Tags: core-data, ios7, reachability, offline-caching

i am using `Core Data` and i want offline sync features inside my app that can function seamlessly without network connectivity. i know in IOS 7 we have background api calls feature but my app have lot of stuff that sync with server like inside app i can add contact, companies, tasks etc. and same have there CRUD features (Create/Update/Delete) and they will also sync with server.

Few ideas that i know are:

1). Check for network. when it notifies that internet available, then i can send any request.
2). sending requests in background (IOS 7).
3).Cache policy. But i don't know much about its implementation about server.

i want to know any best idea of implementing offline sync for both server side and IOS side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to sync uploaded data even in no-network conditions, the best way is really to create an alternate model to hold objects that have been changed locally but have not yet reached the server.

in this way, you can contain all the latest client changes and upload them reliably to the server using your CRUD routes, this can be fully automated.